# improper integral and integration by parts

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How do I apply integration by part to an improper integral?

I'm condidering an integral

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} g(t)f(t)dt$$ so I guess I can do

$$\lim_{b\rightarrow -\infty}\int^0_{b} g(t)f(t)dt + \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int^a_{0} g(t)f(t)dt $$ and then consider these summands one at a time. Such that

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int^a_{0} g(t)f(t)dt = \lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}\left( [g(t)F(t)]_0^a - \int_0^a g'(t)F(t)dt\right),$$

where $f(t) = \frac{d}{dt}F(t)$?

And a follows up question: If I then consider

$$\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty}[g(t)F(t)]_0^a = g(0)F(0) - \lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} f(a)F(a)$$ and 
$$\lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty}[g(t)F(t)]_b^0 = \lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} f(b)F(b) - g(0)F(0)$$

and I have the condition that

$$\lim_{b \rightarrow -\infty} f(b)F(b)  = \lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} f(a)F(a)$$

does it then follows that

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} g(t)f(t)dt = - \int_{-\infty}^\infty g'(t) F(t) dt$$ ?

Comment: Are g(t), f(t) integrable by assumption?

Comment: They are now ... if that is what it takes - the function I will be considering are pretty well behaved $g(t)$ is many times differentiable, varying in the number of times and is a density. And $F(t)$ is a kernel function or a kernel function differentiated.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula for proper integrals can be written as

$$ \left. \int_a^b g(t) f(t)\; dt = g(t) F(t)\right|_{t=a}^b - \int_a^b g'(t) F(t)\; dt $$

So if the right side has a limit as $a \to -\infty$ and $b \to +\infty$, then the left side has the same limit.

Comment: ok, yeah, but exactly how does this bear on the question at hand? Could you exapand? Just assume I'm bad at math, im not a mathematician.

Comment: In particular does that mean that $\lim_{a\rightarrow -\infty} g(a)F(a) = \lim_{b\rightarrow \infty} g(a)F(a)$ implies $[g(t)F(t)]_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 0$ and hence $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)f(t) dt= - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g'(t)F(t) dt$ assuming existence of necessary limits?